# Received notification for hidden shared Google calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I have two Google accounts, a personal account and a work account. I shared the work calendar with my personal account, but the details are hidden (there's no way to make it not hidden).

At home, I use my personal account, but I want to receive work notifications. For some reason, I don't get notifications for hidden events. Since Google Calendar doesn't have a desktop app, the only official way to receive notifications on my computer is using the Chrome app. However, this means I need to have the work profile open at all times.

Is there a way to receive work notifications without have a Chrome window open for my work account?

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

There are several ways to get notifications from Google Calendar events like set email notification, SMS notifications, use third-party applications like Microsoft Outlook, use mobile applications, etc.

## References

Follow the link to get detailed instructions

From [Change or turn off Calendar notifications](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?hl=en)

> To help make sure you don’t forget an event, you can get notifications on your phone, computer, or by email. You can change your notification settings for a single event, or all your events.

From [Sync Calendar with a phone or tablet](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/151674?hl=en)

> When you sync your calendar on your mobile device, the same events will show up when you use Google Calendar on your computer.

From [Integrating Outlook and Exchange with G Suite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33322?hl=en)

> If your organization has switched to G Suite, but you’d like to keep using Microsoft® Outlook® and Exchange, you can integrate the services.

From [See Google Calendar events on Apple Calendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/99358?hl=en)

> You can see Google Calendar events on your Apple calendar on your Mac, iPhone, or iPad.